# Hide automatically generated CTest targets

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, ctest

I'm using CMake and CTest in CLion. Annoyingly, CTest generates a load of targets that I don't care about:

- Continuous
- ContinuousBuild
- ContinuousConfigure
- ContinuousCoverage
- ContinuousMemCheck
- ContinuousStart
- ContinuousSubmit
- ContinuousTest
- ContinuousUpdate
- Experimental
- ExperimentalBuild
- ExperimentalConfigure
- ExperimentalCoverage
- ExperimentalMemCheck
- ExperimentalStart
- ExperimentalSubmit
- ExperimentalTest
- ExperimentalUpdate
- Nightly
- NightlyBuild
- NightlyConfigure
- NightlyCoverage
- NightlyMemCheck
- NightlyStart
- NightlySubmit
- NightlyTest
- NightlyUpdate

These all show up in CLion. Quite annoying as I'm sure you'll agree. Is there solution to remove them? I'm open to any solution:

1. Get CTest to not generate them in the first place.
2. Delete the targets after CTest has created them.
3. A setting in CLion to hide them.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45169854/cmake-in-qtcreator-4-3-shows-many-automatic-targets-how-to-remove-hide-them) Q/A on SO. That probably solves also your problems.

Comment: Just to note that I've logged a feature request for CMake to provide a way to prevent the creation of these targets:
https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/21730

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution that I'm not sure works 100% is to go to Run->Edit Configurations... in CLion and simply delete all the targets you don't want.

This seems to survive reloading the CMake configuration, and `make clean`.

Answer (score 11):

Unless you are using CDash, the solution is very simple.

In your CMakefile replace

```
include(CTest)
```

with

```
enable_testing()
```

Answer (score 6):

**Hack warning - below hack relies on an internal implementation detail ([CTestTargets.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/v3.19.6/Modules/CTestTargets.cmake)), and thus not guaranteed to work with any CMake version.**

If one cannot avoid `include(CTest)`, since certain CTest functionalities are needed and aren't available by `enable_testing()`, such as Valgrind integration, generation of the automatic CTest targets could be avoided altogether using the following hack:

```
set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY CTEST_TARGETS_ADDED 1) # hack to prevent CTest added targets
include (CTest)
```

Setting `CTEST_TARGETS_ADDED` to `1` prior to including `CTest` will prevent generation of the automatic CTest targets.

I've tested this with CMake 3.6, and it should be working through CMake 3.19.6 (in which the `CTEST_TARGETS_ADDED` macro is still being used).

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution to manage the clutter that doesn't require deleting those targets (so you can easily go back to them if the need arises) is to create a sub-folder in the `Edit Configurations...` menu where you can drag and move all the entries you are not interested to see at the top level.

Note that this applies more generally to various target types, not just test related ones.
Here is an example here where I put all that stuff in a `misc` folder :

[image]